# How do I check my available storage in my Adobe cloud storage?

Tags: online-storage

I have an Adobe cloud storage account. How do I check my available storage in my Adobe cloud storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may view your available storage in your Adobe cloud storage at this address: https://assets2.adobe.com/activity/settings:

[image]

Comment: You should use some font anti-aliasing on your screen :)

Comment: @bers agreed [Some fonts are difficult to read in Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, while MSIE works fine](https://superuser.com/q/1293265/116475)